# How to serve two different applications from the same domain

Tags: proxy, dns, content-management-system, reverse, legacy

We have a legacy application that does two things: serve dynamic content and do transactions with registered users, all from a single domain `thedomain.com`.

We want to update/change the CMS (part of the legacy server that serves dynamic content), but keep the existing server for the transactional part. And we want to serve it all from the same domain.

So if we have today `thedomain.com/cms/page1.html` and `thedomain.com/business/step1` coming from the same server, in the future we would like those to come from different servers (placed in different data centers and operated by different providers).

What's the best way to set this up? It should use a reverse proxy, yes? but where is it best to set it up and how? Should the reverse proxy be "near" the legacy server or near the new one, or does it matter at all? Are there specific caveats as regards to sharing sessions, etc. in setting a reverse proxy for this use?

Comment: if you're going to eventually destroy the legacy server, leave the proxy "near" the new one, and I would suggest using nginx as a reverse-proxy for this.

Answer (score -1):

Your proxy should be the server which has the most traffic, so the biggest chunk of data does not need to go through 2 servers, but why dont you use subdomains, so cms.example.com/ instead of example.com/cms/ ?